# The entity or complex type '*' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Eu não posso fazer isso?

```
public List<Filial> GetAll()
{
    //Mostra todos os registros incluindo os desativados para os Administradores
    var ret = _db.Filiais.AsNoTracking()
                 .Where(e => e.Visible)
                 .OrderBy(e => e.FilialNome)
                 .Select(x => new Filial
                 {
                     FilialId = x.FilialId,
                     FilialNome = x.FilialNome,
                     FilialEndereco = x.FilialEndereco,
                     FilialBairro = x.FilialBairro,
                     FilialFixPhone = x.FilialFixPhone
                  }).ToList();

    return ret;
}
```

o erro

> The entity or complex type 'CCValemixEF.Infra.Data.Context.Filial'
>   cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso mesmo, não pode. O próprio erro diz

> The entity or complex type 'CCValemixEF.Infra.Data.Context.Filial' **cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.**

Tradução livre

> A entidade ou tipo complexo 'CCValemixEF.Infra.Data.Context.Filial' **não pode ser criado numa query *LINQ to Entitites***

O correto é trazer os dados pra memória, usando `.ToList()` pra depois construir os objetos.

Preste atenção pra sempre deixar o `ToList()` depois do `Where()` e do `OrderBy()` pra que os dados sejam filtrados e ordenados ainda no banco de dados e não em memória.

```
var ret = _db.Filiais.AsNoTracking()
             .Where(e => e.Visible)
             .OrderBy(e => e.FilialNome)
             .ToList()
             .Select(x => new Filial
             {
                 FilialId = x.FilialId,
                 FilialNome = x.FilialNome,
                 FilialEndereco = x.FilialEndereco,
                 FilialBairro = x.FilialBairro,
                 FilialFixPhone = x.FilialFixPhone
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54240/discussion-on-answer-by-jbueno-the-entity-or-complex-type-cannot-be-construc)